# Issue with positioning button at the footer of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There is tableView with footer, which have button and label.

Basically button coordinates is hardcoded to align right. Also autoresizing mask is set to align bottom-right on rotations.

```
saveButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Issue: after autoresizing mask is set, buttons isn't positioned inside the screen. What I'am doing wrong? Do I need to set autoresizing mask of parent view (UIView)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `viewForFooterInSection` such that the size of that view is greater than than the frame size of the `UIButton` that you are placing inside.

Comment: But UILabel is visible and UIButton is OK in case I'm not using autoresizingMask. Size of view is CGRectZero, so it's always stretched automatically, isn't it?

Comment: Lol. Why don't you give it a try and increase frame size and set it manually :) ?

Comment: helped, thanks :) I think problem was in frame's width, which wasn't automatically adjusted using autoresizing